# how to set background of an image and a text /image over it in android

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I'm newbie to android, I have made psd to pngs online and now i have various pngs.
I need to design the UI, in which i have a background image and an image of menu icon

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/shape"
    android:background="@drawable/shapes"
    android:text="Button" />
```

I tried to place them setting as background but i have two images how to do that.,also set text images over it.
my psd to png link is [here](http://s7.postimg.org/dj2cjoil7/pngs2.png) where i have multiple images.

I have [this](http://s23.postimg.org/7kebymwhj/Shape10copy2.png) image in center [this](http://s28.postimg.org/ryy6mg3zt/Shape1.png) in left and above it have to set [this](http://s30.postimg.org/ms2500rst/Shape22.png).

Comment: Could you please explain more? Mark the area of the png , which area you are trying to do.

Comment: not working :( i have done this .i have two images look for that in my image where it is written welcome menu. first is background second is the image icon (menu)

Comment: this is the file i have mentioed here : http://s7.postimg.org/dj2cjoil7/pngs2.png

Comment: So you are trying to do that portion only?

Comment: can you tell us what you want to do in simple words ?

Comment: You set the background twice. Use  `android:src` or `android:background`. Not both at a time.

Comment: i have this image in center http://s23.postimg.org/7kebymwhj/Shape10copy2.png 
this in left http://s28.postimg.org/ryy6mg3zt/Shape1.png and above it have to set this : http://s30.postimg.org/ms2500rst/Shape22.png

Comment: last image  is transparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok try this

```html
 <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#5A99A8" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/menu"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="#40000000"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:src="@drawable/your_menu_image" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/sett"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/menu"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="WELCOME MENU"
            android:textColor="#FFF" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/sett"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="#40000000"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:src="@drawable/your_settings_image" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

And use color not images to get this type of title bar

Comment: do you have any link for making classic UI in xmls for android.as i searched a lot on youtube but could not find .i need to use my psds .although this worked perfect but there are certain things like volume slider as png and other thing.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good solution though

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/shape"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/abc"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/def"
        android:background="@drawable/shapes"
        android:text="Button" />
```